# What is the condition on this while loop?

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I was reading through Chris Pine's [Learn to Program](https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/) and I encountered this weird code snippet in [Chapter 10: Blocks and Procs](https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_10.html):

```
def doUntilFalse firstInput, someProc
  input  = firstInput
  output = firstInput

  while output
    input  = output
    output = someProc.call input
  end

  input
end

buildArrayOfSquares = Proc.new do |array|
  lastNumber = array.last
  if lastNumber <= 0
    false
  else
    array.pop                         # Take off the last number...
    array.push lastNumber*lastNumber  # ...and replace it with its square...
    array.push lastNumber-1           # ...followed by the next smaller number.
  end
end
```

What is the condition being checked for, in the above while loop? It doesn't seem to be a shorthand for `while output == true`.

Comment: A Ruby tutorial that does not follow Ruby's naming conventions. I hope he fixed that in the book...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while output` means run the loop till while has any values other than `false` or `nil`. As in Ruby everything is a truthy value except these two.

Comment: But then, isn't it equivalent to while output == true? However, when I run the code with the latter, I don't get the same result.

Comment: `while output == true` is only true when `output = true`. But what if `output = 1`? Your condition becomes false. However in case of `while output ` it still holds true(truthy) for `output =1`. Therefore the difference.

Comment: Ah, now I get it! Thank you! :)